# What is a good REST API design to fetch questions by multiple tags?

Tags: rest

I have "questions" and "tags" resources where each question has multiple tags assigned to it. Now I want to implement search functionality in my site where user will enter multiple tags and press search. I will have to fetch the list of questions which contains all those tags user has entered. What will be the good REST api url to implement that logic?

I would like to know how address that issue by:

**1.** Including tag list in the request body

**2.** Including tag list in the query parameter section of the url.

Finally, which of those 2 methods would you suggest to use?

Comment: This issue has almost certainly been discussed somewhere before on SO, but the main problem with using a query parameter is that some browsers/devices may limit the size of the query parameter.  Perhaps not likely, but your users could issue a query with many (say dozens) of long tags.  A GET might cut some of them off.  So, doing a POST and using the request body might be a safer bet here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for the quick reply. I searched most of the related questions but unfortunately couldn't find something that helped. Also, in the case of post request, what would be considered a proper url?

Comment: With POST, you just hit the REST endpoint, and your particular API would take care of building the remainder of the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Including tag list in the query parameter section of the url.

How about:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/domain-driven-design+or+event-sourcing+or+cqrs
```

If you were to insist that the tag list be a query parameter, rather than a path segment, you could use

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?domain-driven-design+or+event-sourcing+or+cqrs
```

URI Templates, specified in [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570), defines various [variable expansions for lists](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-3.2.1).  So if you choose a URI spelling that matches one of the expansions, the code that needs to compose/decompose an identifier into a list of tags can use off the shelf technology to do it.

(Pay some attention to [levels](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-1.2); not all template libraries are fully compliant with the standard -- you have to balance "ooh pretty" with "ooh practical".)

> Finally, which of those 2 methods would you suggest to use?

The REST architectural style is focused on caching representations of resources, so the approach of including query parameters in the message body is only suitable for RESTful applications that incorporate message bodies into the caching semantics.

In HTTP, the message body is not incorporated into the caching semantics, so that API is not a good fit for an application integrating with the world wide web.

> The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer, optimizing for the common case of the Web, but resulting in an interface that is not optimal for other forms of architectural interaction.